# cgi:error pid 1217 client {IP}:55101 malformed header from script 'master3.py': Bad header: Database aangemaakt en succesv

Tags: python-3.x, apache, cgi, centos7

I'm currently working on a CGI python script, now I'm trying to test everything out on a Linux CentOS 7 virtual machine. When I'm going to the webpage I'm getting a 500 internal Server Error... my code looks like this:

**Master3.py** (192.168.234.2) (192.168.234.2/cgi-bin/master3.py)

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
###importeren van modules om deze vervolgens te kunnen gebruiken in het script###
import cgi, cgitb
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import io
import sqlite3
import base64

#maak een instance van een field storage
cgitb.enable()
form = cgi.FieldStorage()

#het verkrijgen van data van de velden die vanuit de agent worden opgestuurd.
machine = form.getvalue("machine")
cpu = form.getvalue("cpu")
ram = form.getvalue("ram")
total_mem = form.getvalue("total")
used_mem = form.getvalue("used")
free_mem = form.getvalue("free")

#print ("Content-type:text/html\n\n")
def create_table():
    try:
        con = sqlite3.connect('toets_school.db')
        cursor = con.cursor()
        print("Database aangemaakt en succesvol verbonden met SQLite")

        query_create_table = """CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS data (
                                machine VARCHAR UNIQUE,
                                cpu REAL,
                                total_mem REAL,
                                used_mem REAL,
                                free_mem REAL); """
        cursor.execute(query_create_table)
        print ("SQLite table aangemaakt")
        cursor.close()

    except sqlite3.Error as error:
        print ("Error while creating a sqlite table", error)

    finally:
        if (con):
            con.close()
            print("sqlite connection is closed")

def insert_data(machine, cpu, total_mem, used_mem, free_mem):
    try:
        con = sqlite3.connect('toets_school.db')
        cursor = con.cursor()
        print("Database aangemaakt en succesvol verbonden met SQLite")

        insert_query = """INSERT INTO data (machine, cpu, total_mem, used_mem, free_mem) 
                            VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?);"""
        verkregen_data = (machine, cpu, total_mem, used_mem, free_mem)
        cursor.execute(insert_query, verkregen_data)
        con.commit()
        print ("Total", cursor.rowcount,
               "Data is succesvol in database toets_school.db geschreven")
        con.commit()
        cursor.close()

    except sqlite3.Error as error:
        print ("Failed to insert data into table", error)

    finally:
        if (con):
            con.close()
            print("SQLite connection is closed")

def read_data():
    try:
        con = sqlite3.connect('toets_school.db')
        cursor = con.cursor()
        print("Database aangemaakt en succesvol verbonden met SQLite")

        read_query = """SELECT * from data"""
        cursor.execute(read_query)
        records = cursor.fetchall()
        print ("Totaal aantal rijen zijn: ", len(records))
        print ("print elke rij")
        data = []
        for rij in records:
            data.append(rij[0])
            data.append(rij[1])
            data.append(rij[2])
            data.append(rij[3])
            data.append(rij[4])
#            print (data)
            print ("Machine: ", rij[0])
            print ("CPU: ", rij[1])
            print ("Totaal geheugen: ", rij[2])
            print ("Gebruikt geheugen: ", rij[3])
            print ("Vrije geheugen: ", rij[4])
            print("\n")

        return data
        cursor.close()

    except sqlite3.Error as error:
        print("Failed to read data from table", error)

    finally:
        if (con):
            con.close()
            print("SQLite connection is closed")


#gegevens klaarmaken om te gebruiken in de grafieken
cpulist = []
ramlist = []
used_memlist = []
free_memlist = []


def chart_cpu():
    plt.plot(cpulist)
    plt.title("CPU gebruik")
    plt.xlabel('minuten')
    plt.ylabel('percentage(%)')
    buffer1 = io.BytesIO()
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.savefig(buffer1, format="png")
    plt.show()
    return buffer1

def chart_ram():
    plt.plot(ramlist)
    plt.title("Geheugen")
    plt.xlabel('minuten')
    plt.ylabel('percentage (%)')
    buffer2 = io.BytesIO()
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.savefig(buffer2, format="png")
    plt.show()
    return buffer2

def chart_used_mem():
    plt.plot(used_memlist)
    plt.title("Gebruikt geheugen")
    plt.xlabel('Geheugen')
    plt.ylabel('Tijd')
    buffer3 = io.BytesIO()
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.savefig(buffer3, format="png")
    plt.show()
    return buffer3

def chart_free_mem():
    plt.plot(free_memlist)
    plt.title("Geheugen")
    plt.xlabel('Geheugen')
    plt.ylabel('Tijd')
    buffer4 = io.BytesIO()
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.savefig(buffer4, format="png")
    plt.show()
    return buffer4

create_table()
insert_data (machine, cpu, total_mem, used_mem, free_mem)
read_data()
chart_cpu()
chart_ram()
chart_used_mem()
chart_free_mem()

var1 = chart_cpu()
var2 = chart_ram()
var3 = chart_used_mem()
var4 = chart_used_mem()

print ("Content-type:text/html\n\n")
print ("<center>")
print ('De naam van deze grafieken is van :', machine)
print ('De totale geheugen van deze machine is: ', total_mem,'GB')
print ("<br>")
print ("<html><head><title>Website HAF sportschool</title></head><body>")
print("<img src='data:image/png;base64,"+str(base64.b64encode(var1.getvalue()).decode('ascii'))+"' />")
print("<img src='data:image/png;base64,"+str(base64.b64encode(var2.getvalue()).decode('ascii'))+"' />")
print("<img src='data:image/png;base64,"+str(base64.b64encode(var3.getvalue()).decode('ascii'))+"' />")
print("<img src='data:image/png;base64,"+str(base64.b64encode(var4.getvalue()).decode('ascii'))+"' />")
print ("</body></html>")
```

Anyone that knows why I'm getting the error: [cgi:error] [pid 1217] [client 192.168.234.1:55101] malformed header from script 'master3.py': Bad header: Database aangemaakt en succesv

httpd conf looks like this:

```
    AllowOverride All
    Options +ExecCGI
    AddHandler cgi-script .py .cgi
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

CGI's are responsible for printing out HTTP response headers, then a terminating newline, then the body. When you commented out the "print" statement, you removed both the only header being sent and the extra newline.

Restore that line, change the actual content-type if you want, and switch from \n to \r\n.